# Discount/Coupon Code Block not working on onepage checkout page

Tags: magento-1.9, onepage-checkout, discount, coupon, coupon-codes

I have added discount coupon code block on Onepage checkout page

As, reference URL: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28759782/magento-how-to-add-promo-code-form-on-one-page-checout-page

But, I am getting error "ReferenceError: discountFormsubmit is not defined" on click "Apply Coupon" button.

[image: error on onepage checkout]

I am getting error in RWD theme also.

I have added following code :

```
"<block type="checkout/cart_coupon" name="checkout.cart.coupon" as="coupon" template="checkout/cart/coupon.phtml"/>" in "checkout.xml" file.
```

In "One page checkout order review block"

```
<checkout_onepage_review translate="label"> <label>One Page Checkout Overview</label>
```

And call coupon code in following file:

```
"app/design/frontend/base/default/template/checkout/onepage/‌​review/info.phtml" as "<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('coupon') ?>"
```

Comment: Seems to be a problem with your theme. Have you test this on RWD theme?

Comment: getting same error in RWD theme also

Comment: share code, which you added in xml file.

Comment: I have added following code :

"<block type="checkout/cart_coupon" name="checkout.cart.coupon" as="coupon" template="checkout/cart/coupon.phtml"/>"

 in "checkout.xml" file in "One page checkout order review block"

<!--  One page checkout order review block -->
<checkout_onepage_review translate="label">
        <label>One Page Checkout Overview</label>

And call coupon code in following file:
"app/design/frontend/base/default/template/checkout/onepage/review/info.phtml"

as "<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('coupon') ?>"